# Rails Role model default if doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, one-to-many

We have a `Role` model that is connected to `User` via `role_id`, and there are some users that don't have roles assigned.

Would like to set a default `Role` on selecting users when they don't explicitly have a role set.  Didn't setup a default in the migration.

Trying to use a loop:

```
users.each do |user|
   # some users don't have roles so there are errors
end
```

The Role model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    # Can I add something to set the default role
end
```

The user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :role    
end
```

Also if this is not a railsy way to approach this problem, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an initialize method to the User model

```
after_initialize :init

def init
  self.role =>'my_default_role'
end
```

Comment: This worked great in the User model: `self.role ||= Role.find_by(name: 'user')`.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a simple check for `user.role_id` before you do something role-related in your loop.

```
users.each do |user|
  user.role = Role.find_by(name: 'user') unless user.role
end
```

Alternatively, you could modify the `role` method in your user class to add a default one if it's undefined.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :role

  def role
    return :role if :role
    Role.find_by(name: 'user')
  end
end
```

Finally, you could just create a migration to add a role to all users who don't have one.